# Is it possible generating pdf from ajax response by jQuery

Tags: python, jquery, pdf-generation

Back-end is in python, Front-end is in jQuery. There is a form, form data is sent to back-end by AJAX in jQuery. Some action will happened in back-end then and an object/JSON data has come to front-end. Is it possible/easier generating PDF from those returned values by jQuery? Or will generating pdf be easier/standard from back-end? Can you please provide an example link for generating PDF for those types of scenario from front-end/back-end (which will be suitable)?

Comment: I've done both frontend and backend pdf generation.  The issue with frontend pdf generation is that you don't always know what fonts the user has, so if you want it to be consistent you will probably have to use web fonts.  All it all, it can be done, but backend pdf generation is easier from a controlled platform aspect, imho.

Answer (score 0):

A long time ago, I used this to build something pretty similar: https://scotch.io/@nagasaiaytha/generate-pdf-from-html-using-jquery-and-jspdf